# How to use environment variable in Poco:FileChannel "Path" property

Tags: poco-libraries

I'm using Poco::LoggingConfigurator library for logging, using Poco::XMLConfiguration to configure logging properties. I want to use an  environment variable in path value of logging configuration xml file. How to do it in xml config file?

This is the xml configuration file i'm using now.

```
<logging>
<channels>
  <logFileChannel>
    <class>FileChannel</class>
    <path>/logs/agent-xfs.log</path>
    <rotation>1 M</rotation>
    <archive>timestamp</archive>
    <compress>true</compress>
    <purgeCount>60</purgeCount>
  </logFileChannel>
</channels>

<loggers>
  <root>
    <channel>logFileChannel</channel>
    <level>debug</level>
  </root>
</loggers>
```

I want to define path variable value using environment variable like follows,

${ENV_SAMPLE_VARAIBLE}/logs/agent-xfs.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to environment variables using `${system.env.NAME}`, e.g.:

```xml
<path>${system.env.LOGPATH}/agent-xfs.log</path>
```

In order for `${system.env.LOGPATH}` to resolve you'll need to have a `Poco::Util::LayeredConfiguration` containing both a `Poco::Util::SystemConfiguration` and your `Poco::Util::XMLConfiguration`:

```cpp
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::LayeredConfiguration> pConfig = new Poco::Util::LayeredConfiguration;
pConfig->add(new Poco::Util::SystemConfiguration, 100, false, false);
pConfig->add(new Poco::Util::XMLConfiguration(configFilePath.toString()), 0, false, false);

LoggingConfigurator loggingConfigurator; loggingConfigurator.configure(pConfig);
```

Note that `Poco::Util::Application` would do that automatically if you were using it to handle the configuration.

Comment: Hi Günter Obiltschnig thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but logs are not getting created. If i give the full path instead of referring environment variable then it works properly. I load the xml file and configure as follows,

AutoPtr<XMLConfiguration> configuration = new XMLConfiguration(configFilePath.toString());
LoggingConfigurator loggingConfigurator;
loggingConfigurator.configure(configuration);

Comment: You'll need to create a Poco::Util::LayeredConfiguration containing both your `Poco::Util::XMLConfiguration` and a `Poco::Util::SystemConfiguration`, so that the `${system.env.NAME}` can actually be resolved. I've updated my response to show how.

Comment: Thanks Günter Obiltschnig for your help. Its working now after tried your suggestion. Thanks.